Asp Net Core : Problem with HttpClient post request: method name instead of parameter
Good to know: It's a little bit strange solution but it's an exercise that I have to do as part of my learning at OpenClassrooms.
In an Asp Net Core solution, I have 4 projects:

HspFrontEnd is an AsP Net Core Mvc project
OcelotGateway is an empty project with the Ocelot Nuget package
BookingAppointmentApi which is an Asp Net Web Api project for appointment booking service
ConsultantCalendarApi which is an Asp Net Web Api project allowing you to check the availability of the consultants' calendar

In the appointment booking form, I enter the name of the consultant but I have to use the Consultant Guid to check the availability of the slot. This is where I have a problem. From BookingAppointmentApi I will look for the Guid in ConsultantCalendarApi like this:
 var consultantIdString = $"https://localhost:8884/consultants/checkAvailability/GetGuidConsultant" +
    $"?consultantName={model.ConsultantName}";

var _httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

var consultantIdResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync(consultantIdString);

At this time, model.ConsultantName = "Bob".
But here:
consultantName = "GetGuidConsultant"
[HttpGet("checkAvailability/{consultantName}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetGuidConsultant(string consultantName)

I give you the files that I find important to help me.
BookingController in HspFrontEnd:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(AppointmentDto appointment)
{
    var content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(appointment), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("/gateway/appointments", content);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"{response.StatusCode} : Appointment added successfully");

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        _logger.LogError($"{response.StatusCode} : Something went wrong");

        return View();
    }
}

AppointmentDto in HspFrontEnd:
public class AppointmentDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string PatientName { get; set; }
    public string ConsultantName { get; set; }
    public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }
}

AppointmentsController in BookingAppointmentApi:
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<AppointmentModel>> CreateOneAppointment(AppointmentModel model)
        {
            if (model == null)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Invalid appointment data");

                return NotFound();
            }

            var consultantIdString = $"https://localhost:8884/consultants/checkAvailability/GetGuidConsultant" +
                $"?consultantName={model.ConsultantName}";

            var _httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

            var consultantIdResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync(consultantIdString);

            if (consultantIdResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var consultantIdStringContent = await consultantIdResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var consultantId = Guid.Parse(consultantIdStringContent);

                var checkAvailabilityString = $"https://localhost:8884/consultantcalendars/checkAvailability/GetAvailability" +
                $"?consultantId={consultantId}" +
                $"&appointmentDate={model.AppointmentDate}";

                var isAvailableResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync(checkAvailabilityString);

                if (isAvailableResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var isAvailableStringContent = await isAvailableResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var isAvailable = bool.Parse(isAvailableStringContent);

                    if (!isAvailable)
                    {
                        return BadRequest("Ko");
                    }
                }
            }

            await _repository.CreateAppointmentAsync(model);

            _logger.LogInformation($"New appointment created successfully at {DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime()}");

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetOneAppointment), new { appointmentId = model.Id }, model);
        }

AppointmentModel in BookingAppointmentApi:
public class AppointmentModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string PatientName { get; set; }
    public string ConsultantName { get; set; }
    public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }
}

ConsultantsController in ConsultantCalendarApi:
[HttpGet("checkAvailability/{consultantName}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetGuidConsultant(string consultantName)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"Consultant name: {consultantName}");

    var consultant = await _repository.GetConsultantIdByNameAsync(consultantName);

    if (consultant == null)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Consultant {consultantName} not found");

        return NotFound();
    }

    _logger.LogInformation($"Consultant {consultantName} retrieved successfully at {DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime()}");

    return Ok(consultant);
}

GetGuidConsultant method works in Swagger.
In Debug mode the name of the consultant entered in the user interface is Bob until then:
var consultantIdString = $"https://localhost:8884/consultants/checkAvailability/GetGuidConsultant" +
    $"?consultantName={model.ConsultantName}";


Could you solve your question with the help of the answers? If yes, please mark the answer as accepted, so others can find the solution more easy.

The problem is that at your URL you set the consultantName as Query-Parameter, but at your BookingController you expect it as part of the route.
The easiest way is to change your url to:
var consultantIdString = $"https://localhost:8884/consultants/checkAvailability/{model.ConsultantName}";


In your API project the url routing properties Configured in checkAvailability/{consultantName} Routing template specifies the URL path for accepting requests. checkAvailability is a fixed path part, indicating the resource or operation to be accessed. {consultantName} is a parameter placeholder, indicating that in the URL This location in can accept a variable named consultantName. The value of this variable will be passed as a parameter to the corresponding method. Therefore, when the API receives a GET request like /checkAvailability/Bob, ASP.NET Core will Will map the request to the GetGuidConsultant method with the consultantName parameter:


So you can change your URL to something like:
var consultantIdString = $https://localhost:7118/api/consultants/checkAvailability/{model.ConsultantName};



The routing parameters will be passed correctly:

Or if you want to change the route path to use something like: https://localhost:8884/consultants/checkAvailability/GetGuidConsultant  you can change the route template in api to [HttpGet(checkAvailability/GetGuidConsultant")] 

In this case your url will be like:
var consultantIdString = $https://localhost:7118/api/consultants/checkAvailability/GetGuidConsultant?consultantName={model.ConsultantName};


And the API can receive parameters correctly:

